# Одинаковые данные в двух git ветках

Tags: git

Есть две ветки - А и В. От обоих веток создан pull request в master.
Ветка В содержит в себе, помимо своих изменений, данные ветки А, чего быть не должно.
Проблема в том, что ветку В нужно вмержить первой, без данных ветки А.
Можно ли как-то их разделить?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте ветку от `B` в том месте, где последний коммит перед коммитом из `A` и дальше "надёргайте" нужных коммитов из B командой [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). Мерджите эту новую ветку вместо `B`.